# ¿Como encontrar la long y la lat de los códigos postales de México con R?

Tags: google-maps, api, r

Si se tiene una lista con todos los códigos postales de México y se desea encontrar la lon y la lat del Centroide de la región representada por cada uno de los códigos postales usando el API de Google Maps. ¿Como se puede hacer en R?

Answer (score 5):

## ¿Como encontrar la long y la lat de los códigos postales de México con R?

Esta fue una pregunta que estuvo planteada en www.freelancer.com la semana pasada. Así que me tome algo de tiempo el fin de semana para resolverla.

#### Obtener los datos

Lo primero es obtener los datos de los códigos postales de México. Para eso visite la pagina oficial de correos mexicanos donde esta disponible una base en formato ".xls" que contiene los códigos postales de toda la república al más bajo nivel de desagradecieron. Puede visitar la pagina [aquí.](https://www.correosdemexico.gob.mx/SSLServicios/ConsultaCP/CodigoPostal_Exportar.aspx)

#### Librerías R necesarias.

Se usaron las siguientes tres librerías:

```
library(ggmap)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
```

La librería `dplyr` sorbe para manejar los data freme de una manera mas amigable a la acostumbrada con código R básico.

La librería `readxl` fue utilizada para leer la base de datos.

La librería `ggmap`, aunque su principal función es la gratificación de mapas con ayuda de `ggplot2`, cuenta con la función `geocode()`, que toma como argumento un una cadena de texto con alguna dirección y devuelve la latitud y la longitud de esa dirección. Esto lo hace realizando consultas por medio de la API de Google-Maps.

Es necesario mencionar que el API de Google-Maps sólo permite 2500 consultas diarias en una cuanta free. Esto resulto ser un inconveniente pues en México hay 302288 códigos postales diferentes. Las opciones que encontre para resolver eso son las siguientes:

1. Pagar una cuanta premium del API Google-Maps.
2. Tener paciencia y realizar 2500 (o menos para evitar problemas)consultas diarias.
3. Pedir a colegas que te apoyen realizando conjuntos pequeños de consultas en distintos servidores y maquinas.

Otra peculiaridad que encontré es que al parecer los códigos postales no son únicos si quiera a nivel nacional, mucho menos a nivel mundial por lo que correr la función `geocode("78562")`, esto es utilizando solo el código postal como argumento pocas veces te dará el resultado correcto, pero en la mayoría de las veces no. Es por eso que decidí concatenar el "código postal"+"Nombre de Municipio"+"Nombre Estado", con esto se asegura de obtener el resultado correcto para los códigos postales mexicanos.

#### Código

**Lectura y validación de los datos.**

```
#Se cargan las librerías necesarias.
library(ggmap)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)

#Fuente de los datos::
#http://www.sepomex.gob.mx/lservicios/servicios/CodigoPostal_Exportar.aspx

#Se leen los datos en un sólo data frame llamado codesna(códigos nacionales)
codesna<-NULL
for(i in 2:33){
  codes<-read_xls("CPdescarga.xls",sheet = i)
  codesna<-rbind(codesna,codes)
}

#Se seleccionan sólo las variables necesarias, se les da el formato adecuado
#Se agrupan las variables para eliminar observaciones repetidas.
codesna<-codesna%>%select(d_codigo,D_mnpio,d_estado)
codesna$d_codigo<-as.character(codesna$d_codigo)
codesna<-codesna%>%group_by(d_codigo,D_mnpio,d_estado)%>%summarise(estado=1)%>%
  select(d_codigo,D_mnpio,d_estado)

#Note that the Google Maps api limits to 2500 queries a day.
#Use geocodeQueryCheck to determine how many queries remain.
```

**Partición del conjunto.**

Este proceso se hace para resolver el problema del limite de consultas en la API de Google Maps. Si se tiene una cuanta premiun se puede pasar al siguiente paso con los datos completos.

En total se obtienen 16 data conjuntos de datos uno de 2288 observaciones y 15 de 2000 cada uno. Si se esta seguro que se tiene las 2500 consultas disponibles en cada corrida se pueden dejar ser a los data frame de 2500 observaciones.

```
#Se guarda el primer conjunto con las primeras 2288 observaciones en un .rdata    
codes<-codesna[1:2288,]
save("codes",file="codesna_0.rdata",row.names = F)

#En el ciclo se generan otros 15 conjuntos
k<-2289
for(i in 1:15){
  codes<-codesna[k:(k+1999),]
  k<-k+2000
  save("codes",file=paste0("codesna_",i,".rdata"),row.names = F)
}
```

**Obtener longitud y latitud**

```
#El ciclo agrega las columnas lat y lon a cada uno de los data.freme
#Que fueron creados anteriormente  y guarda el resultado en un archivo csv.
#Esto no es posible sin una cuenta premiun por lo que se recomienda hacerlo con un archivo 
#diariamente. Dejando p.e (for i in 0) para el primer data freme.



for(i in 0:15){ #Para correr solo un conjunto aquí modifique  p.e (for i in 0)
  load(paste0("codesna_",i,".rdata")) #Carga los datos
  n<-geocodeQueryCheck() #Cuantas consultas tengo disponibles
  if(n<nrow(codes)){ #Si las consultas son menores que mis obs acorta mi conjunto.
    codes<-codes[1:n,]
  }else{n<-nrow(codes)} #De lo contrario consultaremos todas mis obs.


  lonlat<-NULL
  for(j in 1:n){
  #Realiza las consultas para código+mun+estado

  d=geocode(paste(codes$d_codigo[j],codes$D_mnpio[j],codes$d_estado[j],sep=" "))
    lonlat<-rbind(lonlat,d)
  }

  codes$lon<-lonlat$lon;codes$lat<-lonlat$lat;

#Guarda un archivo csv con los resultados
  write.csv(codes,paste0("codesna_end_",i,"_",n,".csv"),row.names = F)
}
```

Eso seria todo.

#### Conclusión

- Subiré los resultados a esta carpeta de [drive.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2uk4BKdSI3ibVNKV0pOZEwzeEk)`
- Si alguien más pudiera contribuir se agradecería publicara en los comentarios sus resultados.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte. Veo que en los archivos solo tienes informacion hasta el estado de Chiapas. Tendras de casualidad la lat/lng de los demas estados?

Comment: Hola aylor, te comento que no he terminado de descargar los datos para todos los estados, el proyecto en el que trabajaba  en ese tiempo cambio de rubo. Pero puedes correr el código r y obtenerlos. Creo que reciente google cambio sus políticas para usar la API, pero el código no debe ser muy distinto, quizá solo te pida la `API_key`. Si tienes alguna problema al correr el código con gusto puedo apoyarte.

Comment: @alayor He publicado un archivo SQL en GitHub con esos y más datos, te dejo el enlace aquí: https://github.com/noeasc/CP-y-coordenadas-Mexico

Answer (score 1):

Les dejaré una forma de cómo hacerlo, es una recopilación de muchas fuentes pero creo que les puede ayudar.

En mi caso tengo todo en una base de datos de MySQL, encontré varios recursos útiles en la web, con los que comence a trabajar.

En Github encontré esta base de datos con los Municipios y Códigos postales de todo el país:
https://github.com/khristoff/mexico-ciudades/blob/master/mexico.sql

Varios detalles sobre la base de datos anterior que les recomiendo tomar en cuenta:

- Los estados están mal ordenados: Al parecer la base de datos la obtuvo de alguna fuente pública, es muy útil, pero los datos de los estados están mal. Aquí mismo te dejare el insert de los estados ya que es corto:
- En mi caso no fue necesario crear la tabla países, por lo mismo, omito el campo de país en la tabla estados
- Con lo referente al punto 1 de que los estados están mal ordenados, al parecer el usuario trato de ordenarlos por orden alfabético, pero estos siguen un orden que puedes visualizar en esta página: https://portalanterior.ine.mx/archivos2/portal/UTF/rnp/Docs/estados.pdf

Al parecer los órganos de gobierno usan la clave del estado y asignan una clave al municipio y así crean el ID de estos, esto lo he verificado después de elegir cientos de municipios, así que te repito: la tabla estados del usuario de GitHub está mal, lo demás esta correcto.
Si lo deseas, aquí esta mi estructura de tabla de estados, yo agregué el campo abreviacion y elimine la de país, agregué la de abreviacion ya que las que están en mi tabla son las que usa el SAT y estoy trabajando en agregar a la tabla de municipios información referente a impuestos y cosas así que el SAT provee en sus datos:

```
--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `estados`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `estados`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `estados` (
  `clave` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(33) NOT NULL,
  `abreviacion` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`clave`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `estados`
--

INSERT INTO `estados` (`clave`, `nombre`, `abreviacion`) VALUES
(1, 'Aguascalientes', 'AGU'),
(2, 'Baja California', 'BCN'),
(3, 'Baja California Sur', 'BCS'),
(4, 'Campeche', 'CAM'),
(5, 'Coahuila de Zaragoza', 'COA'),
(6, 'Colima', 'COL'),
(7, 'Chiapas', 'CHP'),
(8, 'Chihuahua', 'CHH'),
(9, 'Ciudad de México', 'DIF'),
(10, 'Durango', 'DUR'),
(11, 'Guanajuato', 'GUA'),
(12, 'Guerrero', 'GRO'),
(13, 'Hidalgo', 'HID'),
(14, 'Jalisco', 'JAL'),
(15, 'México', 'MEX'),
(16, 'Michoacán de Ocampo', 'MIC'),
(17, 'Morelos', 'MOR'),
(18, 'Nayarit', 'NAY'),
(19, 'Nuevo León', 'NLE'),
(20, 'Oaxaca', 'OAX'),
(21, 'Puebla', 'PUE'),
(22, 'Querétaro', 'QUE'),
(23, 'Quintana Roo', 'ROO'),
(24, 'San Luis Potosí', 'SLP'),
(25, 'Sinaloa', 'SIN'),
(26, 'Sonora', 'SON'),
(27, 'Tabasco', 'TAB'),
(28, 'Tamaulipas', 'TAM'),
(29, 'Tlaxcala', 'TLA'),
(30, 'Veracruz de Ignacio de la Llave', 'VER'),
(31, 'Yucatán', 'YUC'),
(32, 'Zacatecas', 'ZAC');
```

Si desean información de los datos que provee el SAT, la empresa BambuCode ha ordenado estos datos en formato JSON, aquí dejo el link por si a alguien le interesa:
https://github.com/bambucode/catalogos_sat_JSON

Continuando con lo de las coordenadas, una vez que tengas tu base de datos creada con los estados, municipios y colonias, te darás cuenta que la tabla colonias tiene más de 130,000 colonias, así es **más de ciento treinta mil!**

Ahora no hay que abrumarse ya que varia colonias usan el mismo CP, al hacer un `group by codigo_postal` en MySQL vemos que son aproximadamente 31,000 códigos postales diferentes.

Ahora para obtener las coordenadas, yo utilice la API de Microsoft Bing Maps, solo regístrate y crear un TOKEN gratuito y aunque no tengo datos actualizados, en un blog en ingles leí que esta API te permite **¡30,000 consultas diarias!**, así que será suficiente

Regístrate aquí: https://www.bingmapsportal.com/Announcement?redirect=True

Cómo usar la API: en el siguiente enlace te muestra cómo, pero te lo resumo para encontrar latitud y longitud https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/locations/find-a-location-by-address

Para encontrar latitud y longitud por código postal yo hice lo siguiente:
`https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?countryRegion=MX&postalCode=CODIGO_POSTAL&key=TU_TOKEN`

Solo remplaza el código postal en CODIGO_POSTAL y TU_TOKEN allí usas tu TOKEN o KEY que te da Bing

Yo utilice PHP, pero puedes usar el lenguaje que tu quieras, la REST API te devuelve un objeto JSON, les muestro más o menos lo que hice:

Nota: aún estoy en pruebas y esto ha funcionado, no he terminado y voy haciendo de 100 en 100 aunque aumentará solo no quiero que me baneen mi TOKEN, ustedes limítenlo a la cantidad que deseen, llevo aproximadamente 1000 apenas, pero en cuando vi que funcionó quise venir a compartirlo

```
<?php
#Obtienes los códigos postales de la tabla colonias
#La consulta que yo realice es "select * from colonias group by codigo_postal limit 100"
#Guarda tu códigos postales en un arreglo, en mi caso simularé que es en el array $codigos
$numeroCodigosPostales = count($codigos);
$cont = 0;
try {
    while ($cont < $numeroCodigosPostales) {
        #obtenemos el CP
        $CP = $codigos[$cont];
        #Pedimos las coordenadas a Microsoft Bing Maps
        $json = file_get_contents("https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?countryRegion=MX&postalCode=$CP&key=TU_TOKEN"); #Recuerda poner tu TOKEN o KEY
        #Convertimos el JSON a un objeto PHP
        $obj = json_decode($json, true);
        #Obtenemos latitud
        $latitud = $obj["resourceSets"][0]["resources"][0]["point"]["coordinates"][0];
        #Obtenemos longitud
        $longitud = $obj["resourceSets"][0]["resources"][0]["point"]["coordinates"][1];
        #Insertamos en la base de datos
        $MySQL->update("update colonias set latitud=?, longitud=? where codigo_postal=?", "ddi", [$latitud, $longitud, $CP]);
        
        echo "Ciudad: " . $obj["resourceSets"][0]["resources"][0]["address"]["locality"] . "<br />";
        echo "Latitud: " . $obj["resourceSets"][0]["resources"][0]["point"]["coordinates"][0] . "<br />";
        echo "Longitud: " . $obj["resourceSets"][0]["resources"][0]["point"]["coordinates"][1] . "<br />";
        #Dormimos 1/10 de segundo para no saturar servidor
        usleep(100000);
        
        
        $cont++;
    }
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo "Ocurrio un error, solo se pudieron insertar $cont elementos.";
    die();
}
```

Chicos, ustedes no tienen que dormir el servidor, cómo les mencioné, estoy haciendo pruebas y solo para evitar algún baneo, no tengo datos verídicos de cuantas solicitudes puedo hacer a la API REST por día, pero llevo 1000 y o ha pasado nada.

Cómo les comenté, en la base de datos son más de 130,000 colonias, pero solo son aproximadamente 33,000 diferentes códigos postales.

Ustedes pueden hacer un `var_dump` o `print_r` a la vaiable `$obj` para que vean todo el contenido que devuelve la API

En la tabla colonias, deberán agregar dos campos, uno para latitud y otro para longitud, los creé decimal(16,13), es decir hasta 13 decimales, en la parte entera no es necesario tener más de 3 dígitos, ya que ninguna latitud o longitud, tiene más de 3 dígitos del lado entero.

Otro dato importante, no sé de cuando es la base de datos de municipios del usuario de GitHub, pero al parecer faltan 4 municipios que han sido creados en meses recientes (a agosto del 2021), recientemente se han creado municipios; el último hasta hoy fue en febrero del 2021, así que solo será cuestión de buscarlos y añadirlos.

En un futuro cercano cuando tenga la base de datos completa la añadiré aquí para compartirla con todos, como aún no la tengo les comparto el cómo crearla.

Éxito

Comment: Yo sé que el usuario pregunto con R, pero yo llegué a esta pregunta porque fue de las más relevantes respecto a coordenadas por CP de México

Comment: Ya he subido la base de datos a GitHub, allí pueden descargarla a quien le interese, es un archivo sql https://github.com/noeasc/CP-y-coordenadas-Mexico